# Is there any way I can import the python 3 version of 'bytes' into python 2?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am writing python code and I want to support python 2 and 3. One of the most prominent data types I'm dealing with is immutable sequences of bytes, so I want to find an elegant way to deal with the disparity between python 2 'bytes' (aliased to 'str') and python 3 'bytes' (specifically, the different ways in which they slice and iterate are very annoying to me).

At first I tried using 'bytearray' because it seemed to have the same behavior in both python 2 and 3, but the fact that it is mutable is problematic, because I need my objects to be hashable.

If there is no way to access the python3 'bytes' behavior in python 2, the current solution I'm thinking of trying is this: convert all sequences (whether they be python 2 'bytes'/'str' or python 3 'bytes') to tuples of integers.

Is there anything else I should consider for a solution assuming I can't use the python 3 'bytes' type in python 2?

Comment: Can you give an example on how `bytes` in Python 3 is different from string in Python 2?  It's not completely clear to me what your problem is.

Comment: here are the differences that I've found so far, try this with both python 2 and 3:
`$> python -c 'print("%r" % ([x for x in b"asdf"])); print(repr(b"hello"[0]))'`
you should get `['a', 's', 'd', 'f']\n'h'` and `[97, 115, 100, 102]\n104`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`six` module](http://pythonhosted.org/six/) and its [`b()` literal](http://pythonhosted.org/six/#six.b) or [`binary_type` class](http://pythonhosted.org/six/#six.binary_type). This will take burden of checking Python version from you.

Comment: Using the `six` module is probably a good idea, but I don't see what specific problem it solves in this context (unless the OP is trying to support Python versions older than 2.6).

Comment: Yeah I'm not really worried about python older than 2.6. But thanks for telling me about `six`, I hadn't heard of it before.

Comment: @yorble: `six` is a good way to write code base for both lines, it is very lightweight, it maybe even a _de facto_ standard (however, there are more alternatives). If you are concerned about what you receive when you access items (eg. `my_bytes[2]`) or slices (eg. `my_bytes[1:3]`), you may take at solutions to similar problems. Eg. I have done the following to make this work in both Python 2.x and 3.x: https://github.com/tadeck/onetimepass/blob/edadd89d2c104078196a2174406064391f408912/onetimepass/__init__.py#L103

Comment: @Tadeck: Checking the python version whenever I access the object is really what I'm trying to avoid. I'd like to check the version whenever I create/receive an "immutable byte sequence" and then convert it into unified form that works the same regardless of the python version.

Comment: @yorble: Well, you can start with trying to port that functionality. Eg. the following may solve the issue with accessing single bytes: https://gist.github.com/tadeck/fa62b1f50b1377cf71c4